# CSS files not loading correctly on github pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I am making a calculator app with multiple themes and everything works locally but the problem is occuring on the github pages.
Each theme for the calculator has its own css file and I am using javascript to change href of the link tag based on the selected theme (theme-1 is selected by default):

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="themeStyleSheet" href="styles/themes/theme-1.css">
```

Javascript:

```
const themeSelector = document.querySelector('#themeSelector');
const themeStyleSheet = document.querySelector('#themeStyleSheet');
let themeValue = 1;

function lastSelectedTheme(){
    themeValue = localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');
    if(themeValue === '1'){
        themeStyleSheet.href = 'styles/themes/theme-1.css';
        themeSelector.value = localStorage.getItem('toggleValue');
    }
    else if(themeValue === '2'){
        themeStyleSheet.href = 'styles/themes/theme-2.css';
        themeSelector.value = localStorage.getItem('toggleValue');
    }
    else if(themeValue === '3'){
        themeStyleSheet.href = 'styles/themes/theme-3.css';
        themeSelector.value = localStorage.getItem('toggleValue');
    }
}
```

When I view my page using github it automatically adds '**/**' in the beginning of the href while there is no '**/**' in the original javascript code which is causing the problem (if I remove '/' manually from the developer console then it works)

[image]

How do I stop **/** being added to the href?

Github Repo: https://github.com/FaDiiiLeo/calculator

Comment: If you want an alternative solution to using multiple stylesheets, IMO a better option is to change a class on BODY, then in your CSS at the beginning of each style add the class so something like: **.Theme1 input[type=range]**, **.Theme2 input[type=range]** etc.. This will allow the theme switching to also be a little faster as it will only be in one single file that will have already been loaded on page load.

Comment: You just need to create a new deployment on github pages - The one you have active is using an older commit where the slash is still there in the source code.

Comment: But @imvain2's suggestion is a good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github shouldn't be changing your code at all. Looking at your repo, I assume you're using the `main` branch for the page?

I imagine something probably happened that stopped your commit from deploying. Since your commit was exactly that change here:
https://github.com/FaDiiiLeo/calculator/commit/00e6c0120da611f340657b357605e387b6453a90

I would push another commit and check whether it's fixed.

Comment: Thank you, pushing another commit worked

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who needs help with the issue:

- I linked my css files to my html file by adding a "." (period) before the forward slash in the link href
- see below example:

Credit: a study buddy showed me this. https://github.com/ramitaarora/final-project-portfolio/blob/main/index.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: `./` is always implied, so not necessary, unless you are executing a command and `.` is not in the `PATH`. `.` is the current directory, and `..` is the parent directory - maybe you've never done an `ls` or `dir` in a terminal?